# Can't get multiple data from API using foreach loop with Fetch API get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

In my project, I need to get organization data's from api firstly, then ı need to get another specific data's from another api with sending as a parameter **organizationEIC** property of my organization data which ı get in first request. I can get the organization datas successfully and set them to items state successfully. But when ı came to the second API request which made in getPlants() method, my program and my RAM fail and ı get **net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES** error for each request. I just put the incoming data to the datas array in order not to setState every time and to prevent the component from rendering again, but the program still crashes. I got some solutions with using hooks but I'm beginner in react and ı don't have any knowledge about hooks and want to solve this issue with basic react to develop myself better.

```
state = {
    items: [],

    plants: []
  } 

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-organization', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      }
    })
      .then(response =>
        response.json())
      .then(resultJson => {
        this.setState({
          items: resultJson.body.organizations,      //can get successfully and set state items ok.
        })
        
      });
  }

getPlants = () =>{
    this.state.items.forEach((plant) => {            //foreach loop with using items state
      fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-injection-unit-name?organizationEIC=${plant.organizationETSOCode}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(resultJson => {
          datas.push(resultJson.body.injectionUnitNames)     //where ı fail
        })
    })
  }

  render() {
    this.getPlants()           //just necessery part of render method
    console.log(datas)
```

THX in advance for your help and suggestions

Comment: `forEach` method isn't the right method to use inside the `getPlants` function - either use `for of` loop or better, use `Promise.all` as shown in the answer below.

Comment: ı'm gonna try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) This *probably* happened because you are calling .getPlants() on every render. You should probably call `getPlants` inside componentDidMount instead.

(2) You may use promise.all to speed up your fetch.

```
getPlants = async (items) =>{

const data = await Promise.all( items.map((plant) => {
     return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-injection-unit-name?organizationEIC=${plant.organizationETSOCode}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json())
}))

this.setState({ data })
}
```

ComponentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/service/production/dpp-organization', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      }
    })
      .then(response =>
        response.json())
      .then(async resultJson => {
        this.setState({
          items: resultJson.body.organizations,      //can get successfully and set state items ok.
        })
        await getPlants(resultJson.body.organizations) // we call get plants here
        
      });
  }
```

Comment: `map(async(plant)` - making the callback function of `map` method is unnecessary

Comment: you are correct. initially i wanted to use await but decided to return the fetch response instead.

Comment: you want to save the results in this.state.plants? then u change `this.setState({data})` to `this.setState({ plants: data })`

Comment: what you mean cannot get any data in plants state. can you do console.log(data) or put console.log in your fetch statements to debug whether your fetch url is working?

Comment: I made the same exact code with your comment but removed the await and call it in ComponentDidMounth, errors not dissapearing but cant get any response in my state. İt looks like its not sending requests  @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: I modified both getPlants function and componentDidMount.

Comment: This is what ı get in console, sorry for my bad explanation `Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(0)}` is this caused async/await subjects ? @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: You have to be a little bit more detailed. Where is the console. from?

Comment: console.log is right above of that line (if ı get your question right) `this.setState({ data })`. Also try last modifies of your now

Comment: I tried running your codes, but i think the problem lies with cors-anywhere. I think it cannot handle so many request, and end up alot of failures.

Comment: Unfortunately boss, i get the first error for each request **net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES**  , i think it caused of we do setState in for each request in `this.setState({ plants: data })`  and it makes re-render component in every setState again and again... @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: It is, that's why you need to use `Promise.all`, then setState({ plants: data }). Please try running your codes without using cors-anywhere.

Comment: yes maybe ı think the same, ı made search a lot for cors error but this is the only solution ı got successfully, whitout that, ı get cors error. and also it gaves **429 too many request** error sometime. So ı dont have any permanent solution for cors. :(

Comment: Then it's not the problem with the current codes.

Comment: your solution is to use your own proxy server

Comment: For lastly, you mean this code works successfully and my problem caused cors right?

Comment: thanks a lot for your helps and suggestions boss, i am very grateful @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: The thing is you `componentDidMount` performs only **1 fetch**, BUT, if you have many many `item`, `getPlant` will call many many fetch concurrently. You need to ensure your API can allow that number of simultaneous requests. Alternatively, you need to split up `item` into separate arrays and split up your requests.

Comment: Hi again @SomeoneSpecial, this morning ı got the solution. Your answer codes above are totally correct and ı can get all my required datas successfully now. As you mentioned yesterday, my error was caused by **CORS policy**. I got this solution (which ı drop youtube link below) and not need cors-anywhere anymore and can get all data's from API  successfully and without CORS error. Thanks again for your help and solution :))  **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yACsnV30N8&t=1s**